# Append the else part elements to end of array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

```
function getQuestionHtml(question) {
    var result = [];
    var result2 =[];

    if(question.responses.length > 1) {
        result.push('<div class="question-answered">');
        result.push('<span>' + question.question_text + '</span>');
        console.log(result);
    }
    else{
        result2.push('<div class="question-answered">');
        result2.push('<span>' + question.question_text + '</span>');
        result2.push('<div style="font-size: 12px;">No predictions found for this question.</div>')
        console.log(result2)
    }
    Array.prototype.push.apply(result,result2);
    return result.join("");
}
```

I want to append the `result2` at the end of the array `result` but currently its appending alternate which I don't want because of the if and else condition. 
Could someone help me to append the `result2` at the end of `result`.

Comment: If you want to append on this condition: `question.responses.length < 1`, should your if not look like this: `if(question.responses.length >= 1) {`?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. If you're doing the `else` code then there's nothing in the `result` array to append to.

Comment: Why don't you just push into `result` in both branches.

Answer (score 0):

By "append" do you mean, combine the two arrays?

`return result.concat(result2);`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use two different arrays, just push into the same array.

And most of the code is the same in the two branches. The only difference is the addition of `No predictions found for this question.`, so do only that in the `if`.

```
function getQuestionHtml(question) {
    var result = [];
    result.push('<div class="question-answered">');
    result.push('<span>' + question.question_text + '</span>');

    if(question.responses.length == 0) {
        result.push('<div style="font-size: 12px;">No predictions found for this question.</div>')
    }
    console.log(result)
    return result.join("");
}
```